# Pointers in java?

Tags: java, c++

When creating objects we write something like this:

in Java:

```
test t = new test();
```

in C++:

```
test *t = new test();
```

So if the `t` variable gets the address of the new object, does it mean that `t` in Java is actually pointer like in C++?

Comment: yes, the objects are really pointers to objects

Comment: Yes. It is a pointer to an Object child.

Comment: To those answering an unqualified "yes," keep in mind that a pointer in C++ can do things that a Java reference can't (like pointer arithmetic, or pointing to a primitive) and so the answer is actually much closer to "kinda" then just plain "yes."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a kind of pointer, called ***reference*** in Java. However, [it's not identical to a C++ pointer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141834/how-is-a-java-reference-different-from-a-c-pointer).

Comment: ... and they're not exactly the same as C++ pointers. So really, `s/yes/kinda`.